# Custom Validation rule not working .NET 5 MVC

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, customization

I'm trying to apply a custom validation rule to my MVC model, to ensure that the value in FieldA will not be less than the value in FieldB when both fields are not null. They are nullable in my model.

**Custom Validation code, "NotLessThan"**

```
    public class NotLessThan : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string testedValue;

        public NotLessThan(string testedValue)
        {
            this.testedValue = testedValue;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var compareObject = context.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.testedValue);
            var compareValue = compareObject.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if ((decimal)value >= (decimal)compareValue)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName));
        }
    }
```

**Model Code**

```
[NotLessThan("FieldB", ErrorMessage = "FieldA cannot be less than FieldB")]
public decimal? FieldA { get; set; }

public decimal? FieldB { get; set; }
```

**View Code**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.FieldA)

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.FieldA)
```

I have other validation on other fields in this model, standard stuff like Required fields and so on. All that other validation triggers and returns the expected validation messages. However, even if I satisfy all my other required fields, my "NotLessThan" custom attribute does not fire, even with failing input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing server side validation? Or is this the unobtrusive validation on the client side?

Comment: @mason This is server side validation only.